# How can I divide an output with 2 delimiters?

Tags: python, sed, perl, awk, regex

By dividing with the "·" and " " characters, I would like to turn this:

```
Hel·lo my name is E·ric
```

To this:

```
Hel·lo my name is E·ric
Hel·lo my name is E·
Hel·lo my name is
Hel·lo my name
Hel·lo my
Hel·lo
Hel·
```

The following code almost does it, but I'm not too sure what I need to tweak in order to keep the syllable dots.

```
sentence="Hel·lo my name is E·ric"
echo $sentence | awk -F'[· ]' -v OFS=" " '{print;for (i=NF;i>1;i--){$i="";print;NF--} }'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$ echo $sentence | awk -F'[· ]' '{out=$0;print;for (i=NF;i>1;i--){out=gensub(/([· ])[^· ]*[· ]?$/, "\\1", "g", out); print out }}'
Hel·lo my name is E·ric
Hel·lo my name is E·
Hel·lo my name is 
Hel·lo my name 
Hel·lo my 
Hel·lo 
Hel·
```

#### Multiple line version

For those who like their code spread over multiple lines:

```
sentence="Hel·lo my name is E·ric"
echo $sentence | awk -F'[· ]' '{
    out=$0
    print
    for (i=NF;i>1;i--){
        out=gensub(/([· ])[^· ]*[· ]?$/, "\\1", "g", out)
        print out
    }
}'
```

#### How it works

- `-F'[· ]'` tells awk to separate fields at any occurrence of `·` or a blank space.
- `{` marks the start of a processing group for this line.
- `out=$0` tells awk to save the current line, known in awk as `$0`, in the variable `out`.
- `print` prints the current line.
- `for (i=NF;i>1;i--){` starts a loop which counts down over the number of fields in the input line.  For each execution of the loop:

  - `out=gensub(/([· ])[^· ]*[· ]?$/, "\\1", "g", out)` removes one field, including any preceding or following field separators, from the end of the line and saves the resulting text in the variable `out`.
  - `print out` prints the contents of the variable `out`.
- `}` marks the end of the for-loop.
- `}` marks the end of the processing group for this line

Answer (score 2):

I know you already have very good answers, but I like the question, and can't resist:

```
echo $sentence |
perl -C -ne 'do {print} while(s/(.*)[ ·].*/$1/)'
```

Answer (score 1):

In python:

Since the split definition is not exactly similar for both delimiters (the dot needs to be included, while the space does not), you need two steps to split:

In a (long) one-liner:

```bsh
python3 -c "s = open('f').read().strip(); [print(s[:n]) for n in reversed(sorted([i+1 for i, c in enumerate(s) if s[i] == '·']+[i for i, c in enumerate(s) if s[i] == ' ']+[len(s)]))]"
```

where '`f`' is the path to your file, between (single) quotes.

Or more readable, in a script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# read the file
s = open("f").read().strip()
# find the indexes of the character "·" in the line, add 1 to include the dot
n1 = [i+1 for i, c in enumerate(s) if s[i] == "·"]
# find the indexes of spaces in the line
n2 = [i for i, c in enumerate(s) if s[i] == " "]
# combine and sort the found indexes, print the line up to each of the indexes
[print(s[:n]) for n in reversed(sorted(n1+n2)+[len(s)])]
```

To exactly match your example, the found indexes are reversed sorted, from last to first index.

In both cases (as expected), the result is:

```
Hel·lo my name is E·ric
Hel·lo my name is E·
Hel·lo my name is
Hel·lo my name
Hel·lo my
Hel·lo
Hel·
```

---

#### EDIT

A bit more sophisticated (and more flexible) would be:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# read the file
s = open('f').read().strip()
#--- set your delimiter(s) + the split rules below in the format rules = [(<character>, <additional_index>)]
rules = [('·', 1), (' ', 0)]
#---
[print(s[:n]) for n in [len(s)]+sorted(sum([[i+r[1] for i, c in enumerate(s) if s[i] == r[0]] for r in rules], []))[::-1]]
```

which gives you the "freedom" to easily add more delimiters and set rules to either include the character or not in the split string.

e.g.

```
s = 'This|is|a|string'
```

i.c.w.:

```
rules = [('|', 0)]
```

will output:

```
This|is|a|string
This|is|a
This|is
This
```

*but*

```
s = 'This|is|a|string'
```

i.c.w.:

```
rules = [('|', 1)]
```

will output:

```
This|is|a|string
This|is|a|
This|is|
This|
```

#### Note

The additional `len(s)` to the list is to include the initial line in the output.

Comment: You also need to include the first line.

Comment: @prakharsingh95 Not sure if OP really meant to include the original line, but you might be right. Fixed it.

Comment: Yes the original line was desired. Good stuff I absolutely love the "freedom" to easily add more delimiters option you provided!